# Remove comment and edit karma walls for an individuals own question

Tags: feature-request, new-users

I asked an anonymous question under a fake account recently (it contained semi-identifiable life-situations so I didn't also want to put my name on it as well)

I realized in doing this -- new users cannot comment or edit their own questions! I know SE has undergone some majors changes in an effort to be more welcoming to new users, and I understand the impetus for not letting users comment or edit questions that aren't their own for a little while, but not being able to comment on or edit their own questions is a problematic loophole where they can't provide any extra information or modify a bad question even at the bequest of other commenters.

Comment: Wrong. New user can edit and comment on their own question even with 1 reputation. You just have to register. You can use fake email, there are more than enough email providers out there to allow easy access to any email address you want. Bottom line: no point adding a feature that already exists.

Comment: You should be able to edit your own posts and comment on your own posts whatever your reputation is (out of suspension), but this need an account, anonymous users just can't, because you can't tell if anonymous request x is done by the same anonymous than the post owner

Comment: @Tensibai I think I must have hit an edge case then -- because I am clearly logged in as the user, getting updates in the inbox on that question, but am also being told I can't edit or comment.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to comment on your post and not under an answer (same for comment) ? If yes, there's not much we can do, that's probably a bug (as it is not expected to work like this) and you should use the contact form down the page.

Comment: @Sidney when viewing your own profile, do you see "(Unregistered)" next to your name?

Comment: @Tensibai OPs can comment on answers to their own questions, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the comments, [you can *usually* comment on your own posts and the answers to your questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work), even if you're unregistered (or low reputation).

In your case, there was a bit of a snafu with the account creation process, which lead to a second account being created, which is why you couldn't comment on your post... it technically *wasn't* yours!

The two accounts have been merged now so you should be able to comment and edit at your leisure.

Apologies for the bug on our end and do let us know if you have any other issues in the future!